# Python sort associative array with float values

Tags: python, arrays, list, associative

I have an associative array which I want to sort

```
  items = {1: [5, 30, 0.16666666666666666], 2: [10, 20, 0.5]}
```

I want to sort items by float value with descending order so after sorting I should get

```
 items = {2: [10, 20, 0.5], 1: [5, 30, 0.16666666666666666]}
```

Note I want to sort mainly these 0.16666666666666666 and 0.5

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: I don't understand your logic. Your list values are unchanged. But your keys are **visually** the other way round. Except **internally** [and for all intents] dictionaries are not considered ordered (unless you are using Python 3.7).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `dict` based on the sorted items of `items`:

```
items = {k: v for k, v in sorted(items.items(), reverse=True)}
```

Note that this will only work for Python 3.6+ for which the order is guaranteed to be the insertion order. I'd recommend using a `list` or an `OrderedDict` instead.

Example:

```
>>> items = {1: [5, 30, 0.16666666666666666], 2: [10, 20, 0.5]}
>>> items = {k: v for k, v in sorted(items.items(), reverse=True)}    
>>> items
{2: [10, 20, 0.5], 1: [5, 30, 0.16666666666666666]}
```

Comment: this solution is not working for this scenario
{1: [60, 20, 3.0], 2: [100, 50, 2.0], 3: [120, 30, 4.0]}
after {k: v for k, v in sorted(items.items(), reverse=True)} this is what I get

 {3: [120, 30, 4.0], 2: [100, 50, 2.0], 1: [60, 20, 3.0]}

Comment: try using a custom key for the call to `sorted()`: `key=lambda item: item[1][-1]`, where the `[1]` means the value of the `(key, value)` tuple and `[-1]` accesses the last item of the array, which you said you want to sort by